# Alternative to External Sharing

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-users

After studying e.g. this [article](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/ultimate-guide-deal-with-office-365-external-sharing) and playing around with external sharing I found it a very uncontrollable and risky, undesirable approach. For a project Site I decided to create regular O365 accounts for the project members outside the organisation, but without assigning them licenses. This way the access and permissions for these external users could be well controlled.
Actually I'm quit happy with this solution, but I'm uncertain because I never met articles about this. Maybe I missed some aspects.

My questions are:

1. Is this legit, beacuse in this scenario many users can use the
   SharePoint without paying ?
2. Are there any technical or functional objections against this
   approach ?

Comment: Can an account without license even login?

Comment: Yes, else I would not have posted this question

Answer (score 0):

**CAUTION**   When a user’s license is removed, all data that is associated with that user account is held for 30 days. After the 30 day grace period, the data is deleted and can’t be recovered, except for documents that are saved on SharePoint Online. For information about how to block a user’s access to Office 365 data after their license has been removed and how to get access to the data afterwards, see How to block employee access to Office 365 data. If you remove a user’s Office license and they still have Office installed, they’ll see Unlicensed Product notifications when they use Office.

Source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Assign-or-unassign-licenses-for-Office-365-for-business-997596b5-4173-4627-b915-36abac6786dc

Comment: Thanx for the tip